# logical operation within vector range expression in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, range, expression, logical-operators

can I have something like

```
A=1:10;

A(1:2 && 5:6)=0;
```

meaning I want to zero out specific ranges within my vector index expression  in one line

Is that possible?

And what if I wanted to zero out all the rest like

```
A(~[1:2]) = 0
```

What's the way of logical NOT within vector indexing?

Thanks

Comment: And what if I wanted to zero out all the rest like A(~[1:2]) = 0 ?
What's the way of logical NOT within vector indexing?

Comment: I edited my answer to also zero the complement of the indices you provided.

Comment: thanks, works great, but isn't there something with logical expressions? Shouldn't it be faster that way?

Comment: The `~` operator can only work on logical/boolean arrays, not numeric arrays like `[1:2,5:6]`. The `ismembc` function is way of turning an index list `[1 2 5 6]` into the appropriate logical array `[1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]` so we can operate on it with `~`. It should be pretty fast. Performing this operation 10,000 times takes `0.13` seconds on my computer.

Comment: Hi, I found a new one line way to do this, now I'll see if it's faster :)

Comment: @user3374479: Please refrain from changing the question title to *solved* or adding the solution to your question. I did a rollback to the previous version. You can add your solution as an answer to the question if you think you add something to the current answers.

Comment: ok thanks and sorry :)

Comment: @user3374479 Feel free to add your own answer if you find something better or useful to know. However, I want to point out that the `~` operator is the **logical NOT** operator, not a set complement operator. The `~` treats any non-zero value as *true* and negates it to a *false*, so `~[1:2,5:6]` is really `[~1, ~2, ~5, ~6]`, which is `[0, 0, 0, 0]`. As far as I know, MATLAB does not have a set complement operator, and you will need to resort to functions like `setdiff` or `ismembc` to get a set compliment. So far`ismembc` is the fastest solution I've found.

Comment: You're right, 
I suppose I wanted it to be a set compliment, when used with ranges
Oh well…
thanks again for your clarification

Comment: But what about a point to point multiplication of the logical with it's numerical self? Could that be faster than    setdiff or     ismembc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
idx = [1:2,5:6];
A(idx) = 0
```

---

If you want to zero the complement of the vector of indices:

```
idx = [1:2,5:6];
A(~ismembc(1:length(A),idx)) = 0
```

Where [`ismembc`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/ismembc-undocumented-helper-function) is a faster, lightweight version of `ismember` that assumes the array is sorted and non-sparse with no `NaN` elements. (Credit goes to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606863/matlab-index-to-logic-indexing).)

Answer (score 1):

Just do `A([1:2 5:6])`.  I.e., just create a vector of the indices you want to zero out.